# Sharing a Connection with full access to LAN

Tags: networking

I have a computer with both WiFi and Ethernet.

It is connected to the LAN via WiFi and I would like to allow it's ethernet port to be connected to another computer that does not have WiFi.

I've used the "Shared to other computers" method and this is working ok for the connection to the internet.

This looks like this:

```
Computer 1 (Wifi)
IP: 192.168.1.10
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

```
Computer 1 (Ethernet)
IP: 10.42.0.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

```
Computer 2 (Ethernet)
IP: 10.42.0.172
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.42.0.1
DNS: 10.42.0.1
```

I want to be able to connect to Computer 2 via FTP over my LAN from any computer.

I can currently only connect from Computer 1 (the one sharing an ethernet port with Computer 2)

For example, introducing Computer 3:

```
Computer 3 (Ethernet)
IP: 192.168.1.30
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: what do you mean two computer can talk? share files? all the computer have ubuntu os ?

Comment: @johncli I want to be able to connect to Computer 2 via FTP from another computer on my LAN.

Currently I can only connect via FTP via Computer 1.

Answer (score 1):

IP routing is hop-by-hop, so the routing only has to know it's neighbors. your computer 2 isn't a neighbor of any of the computer 3's so you need host specific routes.

In your current setup the default gateway is 192.168.1.1 so traffic that isn't destined for anything on your network (192.168.1.0) will be send through the gateway. But anything that is on the network is assumed to have a direct path, so computer 3 does an arp to call for computer 2, but it's not on the same ethernet so it will never respond.

To reach computer 2 you have to route traffic through 192.168.1.10

On computer 3 you can add this route

`ip route add 192.168.1.251 via 192.168.1.10`

There is a static route menu in the netmanager to set this.

On computer 2 you have to make sure that everything goes through the gateway, since computer 3 isn't directly reachable, so there you have to remove the route that is automatically created.

`ip route del 192.168.1.0/24`

check the routing for every step of the way and back. And also make sure that the firewall allows the traffic and that computer 1 is allowing forwarding, but I guess that already happened with the "share to other" option.

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: It's not possible for me to change the routing table of Computer 2, unfortunately (it's a game's console). After adding the route on Computer 3 I can now ping the host, but it is unreachable. Prior to this the packages never actually went anywhere, presumably because my computer didn't know where to send packages for that IP/range

Comment: If routing is out of the question, you can try bridging with brctl, so technically you create a br0 interface with both the wifi and the ethenet interface so all traffic from one side can flow to the other through computer 1.
[create-network-bridge](https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: What I've ended up doing is getting my old LinkSys 1900ACS out, popping DD-WRT on it and creating a Client Bridge with one of the AP's. Basically what I needed anyway as there's a couple of computers I need connected to it as well with DHCP being on my gateway